# Using rbind()/cbind() to append single row data in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind, cbind

I have 6 numeric lists each containing different number of values i.e [1:350] , [1:450] ....   . I am trying to append all of these lists into a singular list i.e [1:1050] using rbind(), but the output I get is dataframe of [1:350, 1:6].

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: You can use the `c` function to concatenate all the lists.  `c(list1, list2, ...)`

Comment: @nar, in order to get a precise answer you should be more specific. Is it a list, or a vector that you have. What does `class(your_list)` return? '6 numeric lists' does not describe the entire picture, in R list elements can mix types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate multiple lists, you can use `c()`

```
x <- list(1, 2:5)
y <- list("A", "B")
z <- list(letters[1:5])
c(x, y, z)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "A"
#
# [[4]]
# [1] "B"
#
# [[5]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```